# syncdb / migrate with djangae on google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm following your setup from here https://github.com/dannymilsom/djangae-blog and I'm able to run static django pages on GAE without any issues. The problems start when I try to use "djangae.db.backends.appengine" as I want to have some basic data stored in DB. I basically don't know how to get my django models synced to the datastore in GAE. When I follow this doc here http://djangae.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox/, I end up using "./manage.py --sandbox=remote makemigrations" but that gives me nasty error like this:
https://gist.github.com/sikor80/334241b17b44b94b95c5

and additionally when I try to sync my models locally and get this error https://gist.github.com/sikor80/879b5df7fd8ff6d42f88, my models are very simple as shown https://gist.github.com/sikor80/1c294b3339a2ff91c343

Would anybody know how to deal with it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, the errors show an appid name of 'XXX'.  You need to create that project through the Google cloud console first before you can use it as an app-id